# Unable to get user Authorization Status in AuthorizeView?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

In my razor component, I have this AuthorizeView:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator">
    <Authorized>
    <span>Authorized @context.User.IsInRole("Administrator")</span>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <span>Not Authorized @context.User.IsInRole("Administrator")</span>
</NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I also tried to put all the role there is but to no avail:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator,Supervisor,Operator,Readonly">
```

When I login using user with Administrator Role, it seems the user role is not Administrator. the @context.User.IsInRole("Administrator") will always return False. This App I'm building, one user can only have one Role. DId I miss anything here? Do I need to add anything in the Program.cs?
Here is the Program.cs file:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#bwapp");

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BWebApp.ServerAPI", (sp, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
            client.EnableIntercept(sp);
        })
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BWebApp.ServerAPI"));

        builder.Services.AddHttpClientInterceptor();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpInterceptorService>();

        builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IHttpRepository<>), typeof(HttpRepository<>));

        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the startup.cs code:

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
 Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(
            op => op.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);


    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely, the cause is that the actual (role) claim type doesn't match the expected (role) claim type. Try resolve the correct name by inspecting the user's claims instead of using the extension method IsInRole. You can do that by iterating or inspecting the @User.Identity.Claims property in your view, it should contain a claim type of some sort with the role claim.

Comment: Did you  `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` in startup.cs?

Comment: @Waller please post your ```startup. cs``` code.

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp. I broke it into commit steps to help people understand the steps. https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp/commits/master

Answer (score -2):

This is likely because the user roles table does not have the association between that user and the Administrator role. Or the Administrator role does not exist in the roles table.